# python type error after third time in loop in line """print (seql, seq)""" following line with """seql = len(seq)"""

Tags: python, types

```
>>> run
Python 3.5.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux

1 [1]
2 [1, 1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 45, in <module>
  File "python", line 38, in conwayseq
  File "python", line 10, in newseq
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Below you can see it looped a couple of times correctly
before giving the run time error.  PS sorry for the sloppy code... 
I am newly learning python and trying to make it easy on myself.

Thanks for any suggestions and help.

```
# conway sequence coding practice
# self learning project

import sys
import math

def newseq(seq: list) -> list:
    p1, p2 = 1, 1

    nseq = []
    k = 0

    seql = (len(seq)) 
    print (seql, seq) # this is the line that gives the error on third pass

    if seql == 1:
        return [1,seq[0]]
    else:
        while p1 < seql:
            p2 += 1 
            if p2 >= seql:
                nseq.append(k)
                nseq.append(seq[p1])
                break

            if seq[p1] == seq[p2]:
                k += 1 
                p2 += 1 
            else:
                nseq.append(k)
                nseq.append(seq[p1])
                p1 = p2 + 1 
                p2 = p1
                k = 0 
    return  

def conwayseq(line,seq: list) -> list :
    nseq=[]
    nseq = nseq + seq
    for n in range(line):
        nseq = newseq(nseq)

    return (nseq)

# print (newseq([1]))
print (conwayseq(4,[1]))
```

Comment: You should definitely format your topic and question better - it's unclear what is going on here. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You're assigning the return value of `newseq` to `nseq`. Since `newseq` doesn't return anything, `nseq` becomes `None`. The next time you call `newseq(nseq)`, `len(nseq)` throws an error.

Comment: @ greal -- that would be great if Stackoverflow would let me.  It tells me I have to have a 1500 points of reputation in order to "format my topic and question better".  I will still try to do better regardless of stackoverflow's restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the logic of your code. Check below line:

```
nseq = newseq(nseq)
```

Function `newseq()` do not have any return type. So, `nseq` is getting set as `None` (*default return type*). Next time when your `for` loop makes a call to `newseq`, it is called as `newseq(None)`. Hence, the `TypeError` error is raised at:

```
seql = (len(seq))
# Raises "TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()"
# Since, 'seq' is passed as 'None'
```

Comment: You are right Moinuddin Quadri.  It is strange how although I should easily see that, it seems like sometimes a coder believes he already has taken care of trivial coding and looks for a complicated answer, instead.